# Dúvida pesquisa SQL

Tags: delphi-7, postgresql-10

Registro entradas de 'determinadas' pessoas na tabela `movimento`, tudo certinho. Agora preciso listar essas 'determinadas' pessoas que não efetuaram o registro de entrada. Essas determinadas pessoas estão marcadas como **true** na tabela `pessoas`. Listo quem registrou a entrada, mas estou me embananando em quem não efetuou o registro. Alguma luz?

```
select m.prontuario, p.nome,m.data, m.motivos from pessoas p left join movimento m on p.prontuario = m.prontuario  where p.ativo = true and m.codmov in (19) and m.data = current_date order by p.nome
```

A tabela `pessoas` possui os campos prontuario(int), nome(str) e ativo(boolean)...na tabela `movimento`, id(int), codmov(int), prontuario(int), data(date) e motivos(str)...

Em resumo, quero listar as pessoas marcadas como true na tabela `pessoas` que não registraram entrada na tabela `movimento` na data de hoje...

Comment: Sem passar a descrição das tabelas fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para incluir o conteúdo do comentário.

Comment: se fez o left join e não houver correspondente na tabela, a informação virá null, então deve bastar adicionar ao where `and m.prontuario is null`

Comment: @RicardoPontual...mesmo com o `and m.prontuario is null` continua retornando 0

Answer (score -4):

Se vc selecionar todos que não estao com a data atual?

```sql
 select m.prontuario, p.nome,m.data, m.motivos from pessoas p 
 left join movimento m 
 on p.prontuario = m.prontuario  
 where p.ativo = true 
 and m.codmov in (19) 
 and m.data not in(current_date)
 order by p.nome
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dessa forma @alexBaiaroski, ele seleciona todos os registros existentes na tabela `movimento` que não sejam de hoje...

Comment: Opa eae @Jones713, deixa ver se eu entendi, qnd vc tem movimento, uma nova linha na tabela movimento é criada, certo? se a pessoa nao passou la nao tem linha nova certo? entao...nao sei se te ajudaria mas eu faria esse script, onde busco todos que nao tem movimento na data X e faria uma comparação com a tabela de pessoas, tipo where pessoas not exists ....ai saberia que a pessoa nao passou la...

Comment: Sua descrição é perfeita: tem um movimento, nova linha na tabela, sem movimento, sem linha add...se puder esclarecer melhor sua lógica e script, agradeço...

Comment: testa ai esse exemplo

SELECT * FROM PESSOAS P
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MOVIMENTO M
WHERE M.data = current_date 
AND codmov in (19) 
AND p.prontuario = m.prontuario )
AND p.ativo = true
order by p.nome

Comment: o script não funcionou @alexBaiaroski...ele retorna todas as pessoas

Comment: entao...entendi que a ideia é vc buscar as pessoas que nao tem na movimento, entao, select pessoas where not exists em movimento onde o movimento.data=data e o movimento.id=19

Comment: Após as valorosas sugestões do amigo @alexBaiaroski (ao qual agradeço muito), consegui resolver a questão:  `select p.prontuario,p.nome from pessoas p
left join movimento m on p.prontuario = m.prontuario
where p.ativo = true
and not exists (select null from movimento m where p.prontuario = m.prontuario 
and m.codmov in (19) and m.data = current_date) 
group by p.prontuario,p.nome
order by p.nome;`

Comment: Show, que bom que conseguiu @Jones713, parabéns!